# Sever-side encryption using aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I’m trying to copy s3 objects from source to destination bucket. Cross account.
My iam-role is setup. And also added the source account iam to destination account bucket policy. 
I have following permission on the destination bucket.

```
S3:GetObject,s3:PutObject,S3:GetObjectAcl,s3:PutObjectAcl,s3:GetObjectTagging,s3:PutObjectTagging
```

My function is getting triggered whenever there’s any object landed in source bucket. But not copying objects to destination bucket because it has —sse aws:kms, aes256 enabled for put object.

How should i add the server-side encryption to my lambda function? Please suggest.

Comment: What makes you think that `sse` is causing the problem? Does it work for other buckets? Some other things to check: The Lambda function needs to send the `CopyObject` command to the **destination bucket**, so that it "pulls" the object from the source bucket. The source bucket needs a Bucket Policy to permit the Lambda function to `GetObject` from it. What is in the log for your Lambda function?

Comment: Yes, same code is working when i changed the target to bucket-b in the destination. Only encryption policy is enabled for bucket-A in the destination, rest of the policy is same for bucket-a and bucket-b. Is there any lambda function code? That writes s3 objects to required —sse format before pushing objects to destination?

Comment: Can't you just add `ServerSideEncryption='AES256'` to the `CopyObject()` command?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein this worked for me. Thanks alot